# get number of rows in join query

Tags: php, mysql, rowcount

I am saving Item and order in different tables. i want to count order as per item.
Here is my table structure.

Table1: **Order table**

```
id | table2_id
1  | 1 
2  | 1 
3  | 2 
4  | 2
```

Table2: **Item Table**

```
id | user_id
1  | 1 
2  | 2 
3  | 1
4  | 2
```

One item has multiple order as shown in the table structure. Now i want to count the order as each item.

I have tried using join but it gives me all row cont: 4

```
SELECT count(Table1.id) as order_count_for_each_item
FROM `Table2` as `t2`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table1` as `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`table2_id`;
```

But i want each item count: as For Item1 is: 2 and Item2 is: 2

#### The conclusion:

As Rahul Suggested this:

```
SELECT count(*) as order_count_for_each_item
FROM `Table2` as t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table1` as t1 ON `t1`.`table2_id` = `t2`.id
GROUP BY t1.`table2_id`
```

This query give the me result which i want initially.

```
order_count_for_each_item
1  |
2  |
```

But the answer i accepted (Bibhudatta Sahoo) gives me the item count which is zero and also the count of item par order.

```
SELECT t2.`id`,
(SELECT count(t1.id) form `Table1` as t1 
 where t2.`id` = t1.`table2_id`) as order_count_for_each_item
FROM `Table2` as t2
group by t2.`id`
order by t2.`id` asc

Item ID |  order_count_for_each_item
1       |   2
2       |   2
3       |   0
4       |   0
```

So I accepted that answer.

Comment: use `group by` and do the `count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this

```
SELECT t2.`id`,
(SELECT count(t1.id) form `Table1` as t1 
 where t2.`id` = t1.`table2_id`) as order_count_for_each_item
FROM `Table2` as t2
group by t2.`id`
order by t2.`id` asc
```

Comment: i will try it and get back to you @BibhudattaSahoo

Comment: Thanks @BibhudattaSahoo just one had one question that is this possible with the join query. or not ?

Comment: You are welcome and it is possible but you will not get your desired o/p :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `group by` here

```
SELECT count(*) as order_count_for_each_item
FROM `Table2` as t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table1` as t1 ON `t1`.`table2_id` = `t2`.id
GROUP BY t1.`table2_id`
```

Comment: Thanks for answer i will try it and get back to you. Thanks @Rahul

Comment: How are you going to know which is which?

Comment: @Rahul The columns in the group by clause have to be projected. Isn't it?

Comment: @Sidtharthan: not necessary

Comment: @Sidtharthan, no that's not an mandate but if it's projected then it should be included in group by

Comment: @Strawberry, not sure what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an `aggregate` function  `Group by`. `group` your data over the item and get the count.

```
SELECT item.id,ifnull(count(order.id),0) as order_count_for_each_item
FROM `Table2` as `item`
LEFT JOIN `Table1` as `order` ON order.table2_id=item.id
group by item.id ;
```